# Syntax error in mysqli update query

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm having trouble with an SQL query. The SQL statement has been passed through `mysqli_real_escape_string` but I'm still getting an SQL syntax error. The code works fine with 99.9% of the site but the following doesn't work. It's probably something really simple but I can't spot it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
"UPDATE text_t SET copy=\'<table cellspacing=3>\r\n  <tr><td  class=\"infogrey\">Secretary</td><td class=\"infogrey\">Some Name</td><td class=\"infogrey\">Telephone: 01794 123456 <br><a href=\"contact.php?type=Contact_Secretary\" target=\"content\" class=\"infogrey\" onMouseOver=\"window.status=\'contact\'; return true\" onMouseOut=\"window.status=\'\'; return true\"><strong>Email Some Name</strong></a></td></tr>\r\n  <tr><td class=\"infogrey\">Chairman</td><td class=\"infogrey\">Some Name</td><td class=\"infogrey\"><a href=\"contact.php?type=Contact_Chairman\" target=\"content\" class=\"infogrey\" onMouseOver=\"window.status=\'contact\'; return true\" onMouseOut=\"window.status=\'\'; return true\"><strong>Email Some Name</strong></a></td></tr>\r\n\r\n  <tr><td class=\"infogrey\">Club Kit</td><td class=\"infogrey\">Some Name</td><td class=\"infogrey\"><a href=\"contact.php?type=Club_Kit\" target=\"content\" class=\"infogrey\" onMouseOver=\"window.status=\'contact\'; return true\" onMouseOut=\"window.status=\'\'; return true\"><strong>Email Some Name</strong></a></td></tr>\r\n\r\n  <tr><td colspan=2 class=\"infogrey\">For General queries </td> <td><a href=\"contact.php?type=General_Query\" target=\"content\" class=\"infogrey\" onMouseOver=\"window.status=\'contact\'; return true\" onMouseOut=\"window.status=\'\'; return true\"><b>Email Cycling Club</b></a></td></tr>\r\n  <tr><td colspan=2 class=\"infogrey\">Any membership queries </td><td><a href=\"contact.php?type=Contact_Editor\" target=\"content\" class=\"infogrey\" onMouseOver=\"window.status=\'contact\'; return true\" onMouseOut=\"window.status=\'\'; return true\"><strong>Email Some Name</strong></a></td></tr>\r\n 
... </table>\' WHERE id=8"
```

Comment: Your idea of using mysqli_real_escape_string is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using double quotes `"` to wrap the query string, you shouldn't escape the two single quotes `'` in the column copy:

```
$query = "UPDATE text_t 
    SET copy='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dblink, $string) . "' 
    WHERE id=8";
```

Also looks like you might want to revise the [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) PHP function and the [difference between single and double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php) in PHP :)

Comment: I'm trying to fix inherited code and I overlooked the fact that the whole SQL is escaped rather than just the params. Thanks